# Convert a string to all-lowercase-words-joined-by-dashes

Tags: javascript

```
function spinalCase(str) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          if ( i == 0 && /[A-Z]/.test(str[i]) ) {
              str.replace(str[i], str[i].toLowerCase()) }
          else if ( i !== 0 && /[A-Z]/.test(str[i])) {
              str.replace(str[i], " " + str[i].toLowerCase()); } }
      return str.replace(/\s+/ig, "-");
}
```

I have passed this test actually, but I still don't understand what did I miss here. Can somebody help me?

Many thanks

Comment: What test?  What makes you think you "missed" anything?

Comment: Oh somehow it just didn't work. if I console.log( spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap")), it'll just print out thisIsSpinalTap

Answer (score 0):

For why the code "passed this test actually" I have no answer - the test code must be defective.

What has been missed  is that the `string.replace` method returns a new string with a replacement made if a match for the first argument string was found, or an unmodified copy of the original string if no match was found. The string on which `replace` is called remains unchanged.

So, while the `str.replace()` calls may replace characters, the updated string returned by the call is not captured.

Answer (score 0):

**STOP!!** Why not creating it with simple array methodes? I created it with **javascript streams** which is worth to learn. You can check all functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp). I also added a few comments to help you understanding it:

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ") //splits the string into pieces at spaces
    .map(c => c.toLowerCase()) //makes each piece lowercase
    .join("-"); //combines each piece with a "-"
}

console.log(spinalCase("This Is Spinal Tap"));
console.log(spinalCase("Okay nice"));
console.log(spinalCase("Super amazing streams!"));
```

If you have more questions just ask below in the comments.

Comment: Thanks man, since I'm a very beginner and english isn't my first language so the way I approach it might be roundabout. Really appreciate your enthusiasm.